# Rails Matrix Population

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a matrix of values that I want to populate, that reflects the performance of certain widget parts in various tests I've run,

```
     **Widget part performance tests**

                     Widgets
                  x     y    z 
              1  fast  slow  good 
Widget parts  2  slow  good  bad
              3  super shit  ok
```

These data are storied in an array of ActiveRecord model objects.  Let's call this array `w`.  I'd access attributes for each widgets in the following fashion,

```
w.each do |widget|
  p widget.part1_performance
  p widget.part2_performance
  p widget.part3_performance
end
```

What's the most elegant way to iterate through `w`, populating my matrix, which is implemented as an HTML table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `in_groups_of`: http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of

Comment: There is also `each_slice` in standard Ruby: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001514